Right-click word to read pronunciation in context menu
Is there a Windows application or browser extension to right-click a word (in either an arbitrary window or a browser) and read its pronunciation (preferably in IPA) immediately within the context menu?
Note: I do not want the word spoken aloud, as it could distract nearby people. I just want the spelled pronunciation to appear immediately in the right-click context menu. I did find a similar post on this site (see, Click on a word to get its pronunciation) but it asks for either the written or the spoken pronunciation, and all answers given (Window-Eyes, Forvo, GoldenDict) are either dead or insecure links or do not satisfy the context-menu requirement.

I've never seen a context menu item that can return its result within the context menu itself (but years of embarrassing experiences have taught me to avoid saying that something is impossible!).
Have you seen such an animal that people like me might reverse engineer?

@BillBell If it's impossible, I'd accept a feature that after clicking the context menu item ("View pronunciation") gave the pronunciation immediately (without more than, maybe, five seconds of loading).

Context menus don't work the way you'd like them to work. As the name suggests, they're all about context, which can totally differ per application. If you take a look at Chrome's and Microsoft Word's context menus, for example, you'll notice they're entirely different.

@Destroy666 You're right, but sometimes that context is word-related. I thought at minimum there would be a Chrome plug-in...

I had a quick look earlier and the only close plugin uses the extension button. Anything else is English only or has only spoken pronunciation.

@Destroy666 Which plugin was it?

I don't remember, maybe Wiktionary. Just type "pronunciation" in Chrome Web Store and you'll find it, there aren't many options
